# Updated way of including latin and greek languages?

Tags: miktex, polyglossia, greek, datetime2, latin

I have had the following code in my custom classes to handle latin and greek:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage[variant=classic]{latin}
\newfontfamily\latinfont[Script=Latin,Scale=MatchLowercase]{Garamond}
\newfontfamily\latinfontsf[Script=Latin,Scale=MatchLowercase]{Garamond}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient, numerals=arabic]{greek}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{DejaVu Serif}
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf[Script=Greek]{DejaVu Serif}
\usepackage{datetime2}
\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

This has worked well for years. After I updated MikTeX today (I don't update often so not necessarily a recent change), it throws an error saying that grc is missing from tracklang.tex? Looks like it is called from datetime2? Error messages don't make sense to me, but it works when I comment out those lines above from my classes.

Update: After trying various things, if I only comment out the bottom two rows of the above (newfontfamily with greek), a PDF document is produced which only contains the text "grcdatetime2-.ldf".

What is the new correct way to use polyglossia with latin and greek custom fonts?

Comment: I do not know about above code, but you should always include a Minimal Working Example - just enough code that would compile without error on your old system and still give the error on your new system. Start with `\documentclass{article}` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The above is a Minimal Not Working Example, as you can paste it in any document preamble (before begin{document}) and get the errors I describe.

Comment: Note that it is a annoyance to those who are trying to help when you don't provide something that can be copied and pasted into a file and tested directly. Many of us will not touch questions like that as it is a waste of time.

Comment: Fine, I added the four rows (!) that are needed to make it a fully functioning TeX document, can be saved and run, to produce the errors. Thanks for the downvote, since the question is perfectly valid.

Comment: Looks like an issue with `tracklang`. You may want to report this to the developer.

Comment: None of us here downvoted (they are all know contributers and proper downvoters leave a comment as to why they downvoted). Once you've answered enough questions where the person has left out information or when you look at as many questions as some of us do, you'll realise why this request is the single most common request on here.

Comment: I get no errors with the OP MWE, if I change the greek variant to `polytonic` instead of `ancient`.  Like so `\setotherlanguage[variant=polytonic, numerals=arabic]{greek}`.   Apparently the current `datetime-2` does not know about the `ancient` variant of Greek.

Comment: Another possibility is just to leave out `datetime2`.   Since polyglossia already sets up greek date commands.

Comment: I did not know about polytonic. Looking at wikipedia, polytonic = ancient greek, so I guess this is the new and updated way to use it, and "ancient" is now deprecated... at least it compiles now without errors. @Thruston would you mind posting your comment as an answer so I can mark it solved?

Comment: *pace* Wikipedia, the two options are not quite the same in `polyglossia`.  I think the hyphenation definitions of `ancient` are a superset of `polytonic` -- I can post this as an answer, but I still think that datetime2 needs updating to allow `ancient` as a Greek variant.